# How to run Enlightenment on Wayland on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, wayland, enlightenment

I'd like to run an Enlightenment on Wayland session on Arch Linux, I read the [Arch Linux](https://www.enlightenment.org/distros/archlinux-start) article at enlightenment.org, but it seems to be outdated as enlightenment-wayland-git no longer exists in the Arch User Repository (AUR). I tried installing enlightenment-git from the AUR, in the hope it was a typo, but it will not build due to missing dependencies (e.g. gitmeson). The official enlightenment package does not have an enlightenment_wayland_start binary so I can't start it using that. I tried starting it with `ELM_DISPLAY=wl ELM_ACCEL=opengl enlightenment_start` based on what is said near the end of the [Wayland](https://www.enlightenment.org/about-wayland) article at enlightenment.org, but it does not seem this is a Wayland session that it started. The window enlightenment started in was called "WL-X11"

[image]

plus I could run Plank in it, but under other Wayland sessions Plank won't start because it can't run on Wayland.

Comment: Wow, that enlightenment documentation must be *way* out of date - `enlightenment-wayland-git` doesn't even exist in the [AUR archive](https://github.com/aur-archive), which goes back several years.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out build instructions on their [Github page](https://github.com/Enlightenment/enlightenment/blob/master/README.wayland). This Readme is dated November 2017:

> Running Enlightenment as a Wayland compositor is not considered "safe"
>   for everyday desktop use